# Coloring Each Materialize.css Collections Action Differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I'm currently using [Fylipp's Materialize Collection Actions](https://fylipp.github.io/materialize-collection-actions/), and as the title suggests, am trying to color different actions in my collection items differently. I wrote a script (see the first of the code blocks below) to create two actions for each collection item. Since the icons' image names are given in the innerHTML of the corresponding `<i>` tags (and innerHTML is inaccessible in vanilla css), I thought I would create an extra attribute for each icon called `title = innerHTML`. I could then change the colors of each in my css file (see the second of the below code blocks).

```
var $ = require("jquery");

$(document).ready(async function()
{
    await MaterializeCollectionActions.configureActions($('#collection-id'),
    [
        {
            name: 'delete',
            callback: function (collectionItem, collection)
            {
                $(collectionItem).remove();
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'play_arrow',
            callback: function (collectionItem, collection)
            {
                console.log("Played!");
            }
        }
    ]);
    const icons = document.getElementsByTagName("i");
    console.log(icons.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++)
    {
        const icon = icons[i];
        icon.title = icon.innerHTML;
    }
});
```

.

```
i[title = 'delete']
{
     color: grey;
}

i[title = 'play_arrow']
{
     color: #00e676;
}
```

However, for some reason, `icons.length` is `0` most of the time I run my app (everything works as intended ~1/5 of the time). The inconsistent behavior implies to me that this is an asynchronous issue, but I thought adding the async/await commands would mean that `const icons = document.getElementsByTagName("i");` is not run until the previous function is complete. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to "Jensa" from "The Programmer's Hangout" Discord for the following solution: Simply wrapping the JS after the `MaterializeCollectionActions.configureActions()` call in `setTimeout()` like the following:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const icons = document.getElementsByTagName("i");
  console.log(icons.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++)
  {
      const icon = icons[i];
      icon.title = icon.innerHTML;
  }
}, 0);
```

fixes the issue. The reason this works is explained very well here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ. Essentially, since `setTimeout()` is an asynchronous function, it moves the code within its callback function off the stack and onto the callback queue, which is only called when the stack is empty (i.e. when the synchronous stuff is done running).